# JavaCC grammar - proper lexing

Tags: javacc

I have a JavaCC grammar with following definitions:

```
<REGULAR_IDENTIFIER : (["A"-"Z"])+ > // simple identifier like say "DODGE"
<_LABEL : (["A"-"Z"])+ (":") > // label, eg "DODGE:"
<DOUBLECOLON : "::">
<COLON : ":">
```

Right now "DODGE::" lexed as  `<_LABEL> <COLON>` ("DODGE:" ":")
but i need to lex it as `<REGULAR_IDENTIFIER> <DOUBLECOLON>` ("DODGE" "::")

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will work

```
MORE: { < (["A"-"Z"])+ :S0 > } // Could be identifier or label.
<S0> TOKEN: { <LABEL : ":" : DEFAULT> } // label, eg "DODGE:"
<S0> TOKEN: { <IDENTIFIER : "" : DEFAULT > } // simple identifier like say "DODGE"
<S0> TOKEN: { <IDENTIFIER : "::" { matchedToken.image = image.substring(0,image.size()-2) ; } : S1 > }
<S1> TOKEN: { <DOUBLECOLON : "" { matchedToken.image =  "::" ; } : DEFAULT> }
<DOUBLECOLON : "::">
<COLON : ":">
```

Note that "DODGE:::" is three tokens, not two.

Comment: "as is" - unfortunately no (syntax errors etc), but i get the idea, will work on it

Answer (score 0):

In javacc the maximal match rule (longest prefix match rule) is used see:
http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#more-than-one

This means that the _LABEL token will be matched before the REGULAR_IDENTIFIER token, as the _LABEL token will contain more characters. This means that what you are trying to do should not be done in the tokenizer.

I have written a parser which recognizes the grammar correctly, I use the parser for recognizing the _LABEL's, instead of the tokenizer:

```
options {
    STATIC = false;
}

PARSER_BEGIN(Parser)

import java.io.StringReader;

public class Parser {

    //Main method, parses the first argument to the program
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("Parseing: " + args[0]);
        Parser parser = new Parser(new StringReader(args[0]));
        parser.Start();
    }
}

PARSER_END(Parser)

//The _LABEL will be recognized by the parser, not the tokenizer
TOKEN :
{
    <DOUBLECOLON : "::"> //The double token will be preferred to the single colon due to the maximal munch rule
    |
    <COLON : ":">
    |
    <REGULAR_IDENTIFIER : (["A"-"Z"])+ > // simple identifier like say "DODGE"
}

/** Root production. */
void Start() :
{}
{
    ( 
        LOOKAHEAD(2) //We need a lookahead of two, to see if this is a label or not
        <REGULAR_IDENTIFIER> <COLON> { System.err.println("label"); } //Labels, should probably be put in it's own production
        | <REGULAR_IDENTIFIER> { System.err.println("reg_id"); }  //Regulair identifiers
        | <DOUBLECOLON> { System.err.println("DC"); } 
        | <COLON> { System.err.println("C"); } 
    )+
}
```

In a real you should of cause move the `<REGULAR_IDENTIFIER> <COLON>` to a `_label` production.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that <_LABEL> can happen at almost any place where <REGULAR_IDENTIFIER> can be
This is from T-SQL syntax
EG 

    select * from Table1 Bunny
    select * from Table1 Bunny:

first line - "Bunny" is a table alias
second line - "Bunny" is a label
In prev version of grammar i've used the same techinque as you suggested but it were too many difficulites with other part of grammar

Comment: If there are any SKIP rules, then this might not work. For example is spaces are skipped, then `"DODGE :"` will be treated as a label in @jakobht's solution, but as an IDENTIFIER followed by a COLON in my solution. My guess was that the latter behaviour is what the OP wanted.